# how to compile aidl file in android project?

Tags: android, aidl

Hi can anyone tell me where to place aidl file in project tree and how to use it in project source. Will aidl file gets compiled, If i build apk ?? How to use it in eclipse ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language) is similar to other IDLs
>   you might have worked with. It allows you to define the programming
>   interface that both the client and service agree upon in order to
>   communicate with each other using interprocess communication (IPC)

**Where to place aidl file ?**

> Save aidl file in the source code (in the src/ directory) of both the
>   application hosting the service and any other application that binds
>   to the service.

**Will aidl file gets compiled, If i build apk ?**

> When you compile your project, then there project automatically
>   generate one file in gen foler.

Look at [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers, you can also build just the AIDL files.

**Android Studio 3.0.1** (It should be the same in Android Studio 2.x.x):

***View*** -> ***Tool Windows*** -> ***Gradle***

Right-click on ***compileDebugAidl*** -> ***Run***

[image: Compiling AIDL only. Right-click and execute]

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is wondering where to place the AIDL file when using the Gradle build system (since the docs still tell you to place it in `src/`):

**Under Gradle you have to place the AIDL file in `src/main/aidl/` for it to be automatically detected.**

During the build the Java interface and stub implementation is then put into *build/generated/source/aidl/{debug,release}/*, otherwise the information provided by [Chirag Raval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614807/chirag-raval) is still correct.